# Connecting Datasets in PowerBi by several variables

Tags: powerbi

I have a dashboard that looks like this in PowerBi:
[image]

Almost every slicer and visual on this page comes from the "visits" dataset.  That dataset is 70,000+ rows, where each row stands for a single patient visit to the hospital.  There are a few relevant columns for this question such as:  "subject mrn", and "protocol_no" (the study they're on).

Well, elsewhere, I have a dataset called "Data Managers" that is the staff assigned to each protocol.  It has relevant columns of "subject mrn", "protocol no" and "staff name"

I have these datasets in my power bi like this:
[image]

When I connect these datasets by dragging in between them, Power BI warns me that they are many-to-many relationships.  This makes sense because:

- Lets say staff member John is the data manager for patient 12345 on study x
- Well patient 12345 might also be on study y, and on that study, staff member steve is the data manager.
- Also, other patients on study x might have other data managers.

So I need to connect these datasets in a way that when I filter to John, I only get rows back from the visits data where John is the data manager for that combination of subject AND study.

When I just drag across from protocol no and subject mrn like this
[image]

it doesnt work.  The dropdown appears to filter to lists for john, but when I check for accuracy, its people with totally different data managers.  Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is looking at this, theres probably a way to do it with managing multiple relationships, but I ended up creating a concatenated column in each dataset of "Protocol, subject_mrn" and then linking those new columns together.